# Lumen 5.3 no routes folder

Tags: laravel, composer-php, lumen-5.3

I created a Lumen 5.3 (5.3 is a requirement) project with this command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen:5.3 myapp
```

and according to the [Lumen 5.3 documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing), I should have a routes/web.php file for my routes:

> You will define all of the routes for your application in the routes/web.php file.

Instead of the above I got a `app/Http/routes.php` file.

Is the documentation wrong? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumen `5.3.0` has the routes file here:
`app\Http\routes.php`

And on the `5.3.3` they moved it to:
`routes\web.php`

So technically the documentation is right, since it doesn't specify which exact version of lumen it's for. But your config is right too :)

Comment: I just figured it out... Thank you anyway!